# Generating content based on input - is it possible?

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

I'd like the Confluence user to enter a number in a dialog, and then to generate some text inside the page based on that.

EG:  Say they entered '12345' - then we'd generate:

> Server name: abc-**12345**-xyz
> SIT URL: http://**12345**.somewhere.com
> AUthor URL: http://author.**12345**.somewhere.com
> *etc*...

Don't have much experience with Macros. Is there a Macro to make this easy? I'd rather not dip into Java, but maybe there is a lighter macro language inside confluence itself?

Answer (score 0):

For smaller macros you could use the macro creator in Confluence > Admin Section > Configuration > User Macros

Here you can create a user macro.

Give it a name and a title (optional a description, icons and the category where you can find it in the Macro Search Panel)

In the template section you have to do the coding.

Add a parameter so the user can enter something
and an output which shows the input on the page

```
## Macro title: My Macro
## Macro has a body: Y or N
## Body processing: Selected body processing option
## Output: Selected output option
##
## Developed by: My Name
## Date created: dd/mm/yyyy
## Installed by: My Name

## Parameter
## @param ServerName:title=Server Name|type=string|required=true|desc=Server URL

## Output
<p>Server name: $paramServerName</p>
<p>URL: http://$paramServerName.somewhere.com</p>
```

For further information see the documentation:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/writing-user-macros-4485.html

beside these method or building your own Plugin, there are commercial Plugins which help you create Macros and other scripts.